# Can't get my soundboard to play on smartphones

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I made a soundboard using HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript. If I click any of the buttons, the audio plays back fine on my computer, but not on any smartphone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <title> Soundboard </title>
    <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var bleep = new Audio();
        bleep.src = "5.mp3";

        var bleep1 = new Audio();
        bleep1.src = "6.mp3";

        var bleep2 = new Audio();
        bleep2.src = "7.mp3";

        var bleep3 = new Audio();
        bleep3.src = "8.mp3";
</head>
<body>


   <nav id="nav2">
        <a href="#" onmousedown="bleep5.play()">Gamsh!</a>
        <a href="#" onmousedown="bleep6.play()">Gamsh!</a>
        <a href="#" onmousedown="bleep7.play()">Gamsh!</a>
        <a href="#" onmousedown="bleep8.play()">Gamsh!</a>
    </nav>
</body>
```

I have some more basic CSS3 and HTML5 code, but this is the basic jist of it. The buttons display on my smartphone, but when I tap any of them, I get no sound. What do I need to add to this to make it work. Any feed back would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no onmousedown event on mobile. I believe it's ontouchstart

Comment: That may be it. I will have to redo the entire page to use touchstart for JavaScript or JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try using onclick instead of onmousedown
**Update 1**
Try changing `#` from the anchor tag to `javascript: void(0);`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Although the onclick option didn't do the trick.